# What is the formula of an APY with an initial borrow fee?

Tags: finance, economics

I am working on a platform where lenders can lend an amount of money and there are borrowers who can borrow from that pool. All borrow amounts are subject to a yearly **interest rate (4%)** compounded on a daily basis and an initial **borrow fee (0.05%)** that is treated as interest.

For example:

- If you borrow \$10,000, the loan would show initially as \$10,005 and the interest will start accruing.

**So the question is**: what is the APY formula for the lenders? We could easily deduce it if there is only an interest rate, but how would the borrow fee enter the formula? We can add other variables if needed, I'm happy to provide more details.

EDIT:
I thought of different solutions and came to this:

$$
APY = (1 + b + \dfrac{r}{N}) * (1 + \dfrac{r}{N})^{N-1} - 1
$$

Where $b$ is the initial borrow fee, $r$ is the annual rate and $N$ is the number of compounding periods. Since only the first period has the base fee, I added that in the first paranthesis, and using the usual APY formula for the rest of the periods. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Let $r_0$ be daily interest rate. In our case $r_0 = 0.04/365$ (ignoring leap years here).
Also let $f$ be the initial fee rate (=0.0005 in our case). If the loan last $N$ days then
the effective daily rate can be computed from the equation:

$$
(1+f)(1+r_0)^N = (1+r_1)^N
$$
or
$$
r_1 = \left( (1+f)(1+r_0)^N\right)^{\frac{1}{N}} - 1
\;\;\;
=(1+r_0)(1+f)^{\frac{1}{N}} - 1
$$
As usual, the daily interest of $r_1$ corresponds to the effective APY
of $R_1 = \left(1+r_1 \right)^{365}-1$
.For example, while APY for a plain daily-compounded $4\%$ loan is about 0.40808,  the
effective APYs caused by the initial fee of $0.05\%$ are listed below for different number of *years*:

- 1 : 4.1329%

  - 5 : 4.0913%
  - 10 : 4.0861%
  - 15 : 4.0843%
  - 20 : 4.0835%
  - 30 : 4.0826%

Comment: The initial 0.05% however compounds over the remaining periods, so I don't see how this formula accounts for that

Comment: @Gabriel  that compounding is already accounted for in $X$, while you can think of $\left(1+\frac{Y}{100}\right)$ as a "principal multiplier". I.e., your added principal gets compounded the same way -- and is reflected in the same APY X, as the original one.

Comment: can you explain how you came up with your formula?

Comment: @Gabriel I simply computed the total amount the borrower has to pay above the principal in a year. For the initial APY of $X$ and principal $P$ it is $P\left(1+\frac{X}{100}\right)$. But if you charge initial fee of $Y$ percent than you get $Q=P\left( 1+\frac{X}{100}\right)\left(1+\frac{Y}{100}\right)$. Your APY now is $100*\left(\frac{Q}{P}-1\right)$

Comment: This can't be it though, because if there are many borrow operations in the last month, the APY should surely increase.

Comment: @Gabriel I am not sure I understand about the last month, but I agree that my answer might not be right. In fact, I think it would only work when the duration of the loan is exactly one year :(  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Gabriel  I've edited my post -- how does it look to you now?

Comment: The reason why I say that we need to account for the borrow operations of the last month is that the more operations you have, and the higher borrow amounts, the higher the APY must be. For example, if there is only one person that borrows 10k in one month will not be the same as 100 people borrowing 10k (\$5 of initial interest vs \$500). 

So in that sense, I assume in our equation we must account for the historical activity in the past month to make a prediction over the year.